# ASUS ZenBook Pro 15 UX550GD heating and venting when idle

Tags: windows-10, laptop, asus-laptop, overheating

New laptop 1 month old. Second time this happened: i just lock it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and leave the house for a walk with no apps left running. I come back after 1 hour and the damn thing spins vents like a helicopter and is hot like pancakes. Screen's off, nothing responding to keyboard. I power off, then back on and all seems fine.

I don't live in a hot country, so room temperature is like maybe 18-20 degrees max. Also laptop not flat on desk, but kind of elevated on some sort of a stand 3 inches of space between desk and bottom of laptop.

What can be the cause of this?

- ASUS ZenBook Pro 15 UX550GD-BN017R,
- Intel® Core™ i7-8750H up to 4.10 GHz,
- Coffee Lake,
- 15.6",
- Full HD, 16GB, 512GB SSD,
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 4GB,
- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there will be an issue from your hardware but I think that you should try updating your windows once and try checking whether your laptop is doing same or it's fixed If it's not fixing then you will definitely have to go to the nearest service center for checking your laptop.